# Vlookup execution criteria

Tags: excel, vba

How can I modify the execution of the vlookup based upon a specific value.  I want it to execute the Vlookup only if the output sheet (sheet 2) cell (Q2 to AB2) contains "Forecast" otherwise skip column if labeled "Actual" in the relative cell.

Finally I want to copy and paste any cells in the Column Q to AB that contain the vlookup forumla.  I believe this can be accomplished using the String function.

```
Sub MakeFormulas()
Dim SourceLastRow As Long
Dim OutputLastRow As Long
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
Dim X As Long

'names of our worksheets
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set outputSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")


'Determine last row of source
 With sourceSheet
 SourceLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
With outputSheet

'Determine last row in col C
 OutputLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

For X = 2 To OutputLastRow
If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") + InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Labor") > 0 Then
    'Apply  formula
.Range("Q" & X & ":AB" & X).Formula = _
"=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(Q$1,'" &    sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)"
End If
Next
 End With
 End Sub
```

#### Sheet 2 Screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will just hardcode a bit:

```
For Y = 17 To 28 'Q to AB
  For X = 2 To OutputLastRow
  If InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Materials") + InStr(1, .Range("C" & X), "PO Labor") > 0 And Cells(2, Y) = "Forecast" Then
  'Apply  formula
  .Cells(X, Y).Formula = _ 'cell at row X, column Y
  "=VLOOKUP($E" & X & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$2:$L$" & SourceLastRow & ",Match(" & cells(1,Y).address & ",'" & sourceSheet.Name & "'!$A$1:$AD$1,0),0)"
  End If
  Next
Next
```

It breaks down to check the second cell in each column first before applying the formula

Comment: It works however now the the Col Q in Match is held constant which is throwing the Vlookup off.  can the Q be variable so it match the Cells Y

Comment: Assuming your Vlookup checks against the Month on the column, I have edited the answer, please check if that will do

Comment: nice.  one Issue I had was that the comment 'cell at row X was causing error so i removed it and it worked in a fly.  Now I am trying to create a method so that I can copy and paste the cells that the vlookup was performed so that i dont have too many vlookup formulas running in the background.

Comment: Do you mean copy just the answer (value)?  You can look into Paste vs Pastespecial